# How can i send data from azure service bus to microsoft common data service storage?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, common-data-service

I need to send the messages received in azure service bus topic/queue to common data service to create power apps.
How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/) connection in PowerApps?

[image: PowerApps UI]